# Getting paypal return variable

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, variables, paypal

I am successfully processing payments through paypal by doing the following:

User chooses item required from drop down list.
I insert a record in my payments table initialising a payment and set the ID of this new record as a session variable, say PayId.
I generate the paypal html (see below) with the link to paypal's stored button for the chosen item.

```html
<a href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=D8TFP8NE12345A">
<img src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</a>
​
```

The client buys the item and if payment is successful paypal passes them to a success.aspx page

I get the session variable PayId and update a Boolean in my payments table with this Id (Id=PayId) saying payment successful and supply the service to the client.

And all works perfectly.

So the question is instead of using a session variable which might get lost is it possible to pass a variable to paypal and get paypal to pass it back to me.

I was thinking of something like:

```html
<a href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=D8TFP8NE12345A&PayId=675">

​
```

Note PayId=675. If so how would I pick it up from paypal in my success.aspx page?

Any thoughts and advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable in the callback url on your success page, for example:

```
https://yoursite......success?myVar=myValue
```

and then read the query param on your success page

Comment: Thanks for the idea but unfortunately a dynamic call back to my site from the button does not work. The call back that does work and that I'm using is set in the button creation and is fixed i.e. hardwired.